# AngularJS change location is not working

Tags: angularjs, laravel, ionic-framework

I'm new in ionic
I'm trying to do a simple switch between two views in a login app:

**index.html**

```
<ion-pane>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Ionic Login App</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>

            <div class="list list-inset">
                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-model="data.email">
                </label>
                <label class="item item-input">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="postLogin()">Login</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
```

**logincontroller.js**

app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location) 
 {

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.postLogin = function ()
{

    var data = 
    {
            email: $scope.data.email,
            password: $scope.data.password
    };

   console.log('bonjour');
    $http.post("http://localhost/authproject/public/api/auth/login", data)
    .then(
       function(response){
         // success callback
        console.log('success');
         $location.path('/map');


       }, 
       function(response){
         // failure callback

         console.log('error');
  $location.path('/index');

       }
    );



}
```

When I click on a button Login the url change but the page doesn't change

Could someone tell me how do I solve this ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: after login you again want to navigate on same page ??

Comment: yes. I want to navigate in a map.html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.js` add a state for `map` like this (with your own `templateUrl` and `controller` value). Make sure to add `$stateProvider` in the `config()`. Also, include `ui.router` to your dependencies. Something like this:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.directives', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider){

    $stateProvider
       .state('map', {
        url: '/map',
        templateUrl: 'app/views/map.html',
        controller: 'MapController'
     });
...
```

And in your `index.html`:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.18/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>`

Comment: think you for your response, I'm getting this error: ionic.bundle.js:16989 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state

Comment: ah ok this error is solved :) When I click on a button Login the url change: http://localhost:8100/#/map but the page is inchanged does the # cause this problem ??

Comment: If I solved this question, please mark my answer as the solution. Regarding the other problem, that the page is inchanged, it could be because of many things. Have you changed the `templateUrl` to yours so that the `html` file is loaded?

Comment: my html page under the folder www so I change the templateUrl to :  templateUrl: 'map.html', and in the logincontroller.js should I change any thing??

Comment: @Sondes Should be fine. Do you get any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: No, I haven't any error in console : ionic.bundle.js:15567 XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/authproject/public  
logincontroller.js:37 success
ionic.bundle.js:15567 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8100/map.html".

Comment: Go to the tab "Console" and show me what's in there. @Sondes. I can see that you're having 9 errors and 23 warnings

Comment: I edit the picture I haven't errors all work just the loading of page

Comment: @Sondes provide me a link to the image.

Comment: @Sondes "Not found". Just upload it to imgur and send me the link.

Comment: Where do you load the content? Angular uses `<div ui-view></div>` as the `div` that the template will be injected to. I don't see that in your code? Your login markup seems to be in the actual `index.html` file, not in a template one. Am I right? @Sondes

Comment: good you are right when I add  the div <div ui-view></div> it works :) Think you very much  Gustaf :) :)

Comment: could you give me a tutoriel to fix a static geolocation of user on the map

Comment: @Sondes what do you mean? Perhaps you should upload a new question on stackoverflow for that that explains a bit more.

Comment: this is the link of my new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323663/angularjs-show-pre-defined-coordinates-of-user-on-the-map

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location,$state) {

$scope.data = {};
$scope.postLogin = function ()
{

    var data = 
    {
            email: $scope.data.email,
            password: $scope.data.password
    };

   console.log('bonjour');
    $http.post("http://localhost/authproject/public/api/auth/login", data)
    .then(
       function(response){
         // success callback
        console.log('success');
         $location.path('/map');


       }, 
       function(response){
         // failure callback

         console.log('error');
      $state.go('main');

       });
})
```

Add a state in `app.js`

```
.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
      .state('main', {
       url:'/main',
       templateUrl:'templates/main.html',
       controller:'yourCtrl'
     })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
})
```

Now make in template folder make a page for named `main.html`

Comment: I do this and I'm getting this error: app.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: angular.state is not a function(anonymous function) @ app.js:11
ionic.bundle.js:16989 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state

Comment: this is my file app.js :                                                                                         angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.directives'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

 .state('main', {
   url:'/main',
   templateUrl:'templates/main.html',
   controller:'loginCtrl'
 });

Comment: Thinks :) no error in app.js but when i add to logincontroller $state I'm getting this error : ionic.bundle.js:16989 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider <- $state