# AngularJS show pre defined coordinates of user on the map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I would show pre defined coordinates of user on the map when I logged it, this is my map

**map.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es&sensor=true"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Map</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content scroll="false">
      <map on-create="mapCreated(map)"></map>
    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar class="bar-stable">
      <a ng-click="centerOnMe()" class="button button-icon icon ion-navigate"></a>
    </ion-footer-bar>
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is my controller

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $ionicLoading, $cordovaGeolocation) {
$scope.mapCreated = function(map) {
  $scope.centerOnMe = function () {
    console.log("Centering");
    if (!$scope.map) {
      return;
    }
    $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
      content: 'Getting current location...',
      showBackdrop: false
    });
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
      console.log('Got pos', pos);
      $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude));
      $scope.loading.hide();
    }, function (error) {
      alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
    });
  };
});
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope,geolocation) {
    geolocation.getLocation().then(function(data){
      $scope.coords = {lat:data.coords.latitude, long:data.coords.longitude};
    });
});
```

**loginController.js**

```
var app=angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.directives', 'ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider){
    console.log('test');

    $stateProvider
       .state('map', {
        url: '/map',
        templateUrl: 'map.html',
        controller: 'MapCtrl'
})
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/index');
     });


app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope,$http,$location,$state) 
 { 

    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.postLogin = function ()
    {

        var data = 
        {
                email: $scope.data.email,
                password: $scope.data.password,
                lat: $scope.data.latitude,
                lang: $scope.data.langitude
        };

       console.log('bonjour');
        $http.post("http://localhost/authproject/public/api/auth/login", data)
        .then(
           function(response){
             // success callback
             console.log('success');
             $location.path('/map');
             $scope.data.latitude=response.latitude;
             $scope.data.langitude=response.langitude;
             $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long));

           }, 
           function(response){
             // failure callback
            
             console.log('error');
             alert('invalid user ');
             //$location.path('/index');
             
           }
        );

        

    }
    
});
```

What should I add to pre defined location of any user in the database?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Code to get data from database and then use it in the map?

Comment: I have many users in my database I want if I logged with any user I access to static geolocation that i pre defined in map or should i use Google Map Image based on Address

Comment: You should do: `$scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(response.latitude, response.longitude));`.

Comment: But secondly are you sure you have valid `map` object in your `$scope` in login controller? I think the map is in other view. So it's best if you have some service that will hold user data in memory (`currentUserService`) and then use this in your map controller: `currentUser.latitude` etc.

Comment: you are right, the object map is not valid in login controller, I'm a beginner and I have no idea about service where I create currentUserService

Comment: If you're just starting then you must slice problem into smaller pieces. This goes outside of scope of this question. First read about services or constants in Angular. So you know how to access user info in other controller. Then also make sure you know how to get correct handle to `map` in your controller. Tackle this one by one, checking if first thing works before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just set the map to same position for all users then you can do:

```
var lat = 51.123456;
var lgt = 5.123456;
$scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lgt));
```

If you want to set it to location defined for each user separately then first access the DB and get latitude and longitude for user and set there.

If I understand your question right, then you don't need `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` at all as you don't want to use location provided by the browser.

EDIT:

Your question about getting data is very broad but the general idea is as follows. You need to create some service that handles database (for example `dataService`) and you can use it to set map:

```
dataService.loadUser(currentUserId).then(function(data) {
    $scope.map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude, data.longitude));
});
```

This shows that you also need to know what is the id or username or whatever identity you use of current user.

Comment: thinks for your response, I want to set it to location defined for each user separately, I will add latitude and longitude for users in database and then what's the function should be added in controllers.js

Comment: can somene answer me

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Think you @Episodex I add this line in my loginControllers

Comment: I add loginController.js in ihe question